# Number of possibilities to change a specific amount of characters in a word

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Imagine there is an alphabet *a* that contains *|a|* characters to choose from. Furthermore, there is a word *w* that consists of *|w|* characters of said alphabet (such a word is just a random combination of characters, it doesn't need to have a real meaning in a natural language).

I'm wondering how many possibilities there are to exchange exactly *n* characters of a particular, given word with other characters from the alphabet (there are *|a|*-1 characters to choose from when replacing each character since a character should not be replaced with itself).

Example:

*a = { A, B, C, D }*

*w = BCADDBACADCBAA*

*n = 3*

So the goal is to find out the total amount of variations of *w* that differ in exactly 3 places.

My math background is not very strong, but I came up with the following naive approach:

- The number of ways (let's call it "iterations") to choose *n* characters from *w* to replace is
  [image: binom]
- In every iteration, each of the *n* characters can be replaced with one of *|a|*-1 characters, which leads to 
  [image: power] possibilities

So isn't the amount of total variations just the following?

[image: total]

Comment: Yes, that is correct.